# Display an HTML table with data from a PhP form

Tags: php, html

I need to display an HTML table with the data that i get from a PhP form. I did a thing like this but It doesn't work properly. It shows the data row on top of the title of the columns. Here's the code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
      Nome: <input type="text" name="nome">
      Ragione sociale: <input type="text" name="rag">
      Indirizzo: <input type="text" name="ind">
      Partita IVA: <input type="text" name="iva">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      $name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['nome']);
      $rag = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['rag']);
      $ind = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['ind']);
      $iva = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['iva']);

      }

    ?> 

   <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <?php
        $a = array($name,$rag,$ind,$iva);
        for ($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
                print_r($a[$i]);
          echo "   ";
        }
        ?> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>|Nome|</td>
        <td>Ragione Sociale|</td>
        <td>Indirizzo|</td>
        <td>Partita IVA|</td>

      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print your data in the first row, without outputting any `<td>` for your data. Then in the second row you print your titles/headers. Change your table like so, see if that's what you want:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>|Nome|</th>
            <th>Ragione Sociale|</th>
            <th>Indirizzo|</th>
            <th>Partita IVA|</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $a = array($name,$rag,$ind,$iva);
            for ($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
                echo "<td>";
                echo $a[$i];
                echo "</td>";
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

More on tables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

---

Edit: I'd also suggest to place your table *inside* the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` so it only gets printed after you submitted the form